# JPA Entity manager persist cascaded to child classes?

Tags: jpa, openjpa

If i havea JPA class Person and Person has reference to a JPA class Address. If I call Person.persist(), will Address.persist() be called implicitly?What if the hierarchy was longer. Would all the child classes be persisted implicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/):

> The semantics of the persist operation, applied to an entity X are as
>   follows: ...
>
> - the persist operation is cascaded to entities referenced by X, if the relationships from X to these other entities is annotated with the
>     cascade=PERSIST or cascade=ALL annotation element value or speciﬁed
>     with the equivalent XML descriptor element.